# Execute command in Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file located on a share folder. I have to execute that file from the local PC. The name of the file changes every day, hence I should find the name first and then execute that `.exe` file.

Here is my `Batch`:

```
@echo off

set FILE =

FOR  /F  %%a IN ('dir /s/b') DO (  
  set FILE=%%a
)

start %FILE%
```

The last line does not execute the file. Why is that?

Comment: Put `echo` before `start` and it should become clear. Also, the first `set` command should not have a space after `FILE`.

Comment: Well .. still doesn't work. I removed space around FILE .. anyway .. instead of real .exe to execute it tries to execute %a. Now code looks like this:
@echo off

set VADIR=\\ABC\Z\tools\AVUpdate\
REM pushd %VADIR%

set LOG="SuperDAT.log"
IF EXIST %LOG% (
del %LOG%
)

set FILE=FOR  /F  %%a IN ('dir  %VADIR%%FILE% /s/b') DO (  
  set FILE=%%a
)

start %VADIR%%FILE% /F /silent

REM popd
Could someone advice how to execute .exe and not discription of command

Comment: Sorry, I can't read that. You need to update your question and use 4 spaces before each line of code so we can see exactly what you are really doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have spaces in the path?

Try this:

```
START "" "%FILE%"
```

The `""` signifies an empty window title. When you quote the filename you have to specify a title, otherwise `START` will treat your quoted file path as the title.